# Splitting nested dictionary with list as Values (with two values) in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas and I'm currently working on a paper for university. I have a nested dictionary:

```
#Normaly this is a dict contains about 400 ID's and is created from an CSV file, so I just added an example dict.
ExampleDict= { 10001: 123123, 10002: 234234, 1003: 345345}

# Just pasted the function I'm using to create a base dict with 0 as values, these are changed later, but are not needed for this example.

def createVDict (BaseDict):
    date_generated = pd.date_range(datetime.date(2019, 6, 1),datetime.date(2022, 1, 16))
    emptyDict = defaultdict(dict)
    for id in BaseDict:
        for Date in date_generated:
            emptyDict[id][Date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] = [0, 0]
    return emptyDict

Dict_to_transform = createVDict(ExampleDict)
```

I now want to transform this Dict into two seperate Dataframes, one for each Value in the list:

|  | ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Value1 | Value1 |
| Date 2 | Value1 | Value1 |

|  | ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Value2 | Value2 |
| Date 2 | Value2 | Value2 |

From the information I gathered in other posts I think the way it is supposed to work is like this:

1. From Dataframe from Dict: `DictDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Nested_Dict(),orient='columns')`:

|  | ID 1 | ID 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | [Value1, Value2] | [Value1, Value2] |
| Date 2 | [Value1, Value2] | [Value1, Value2] |

2. Split Columns using `pd.DataFrame(DictDF[ID].to_list(), columns=str(ID)+'V1',str(ID)+'V2'])`
3. Safe those columns as a list (as one should not alter Dataframes for perfomance sake).
4. Create two dataframes from the lists created.

My problem is that I'm not able to combine the different answers I found for the steps. I hope you guys can help me out.
My goal is, to compare the two dataframes (for each value) with two other dataframes (which have the same structure) using .corrwith(), so that I have the correlation for value 1 and value 2.

Comment: Surely it would be more useful to have that all combined into one dataframe, with another column for "value", wouldn't it?  That has to make data reduction easier.

Comment: Might be, but I want to compare the dataframe with two other dataframes ,which have the exact same structure, using pandas .corrwith() . If there is another better way which allows me to use .corrwith() on value 1 and value 2 from the dataframe seperately that is totally fine by me.
Added goal to post as it might help.

Comment: you data is not a nested dictionary, in fact it raises a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry for that, I guess I shouldn't have used the code style as I just tried to show the way the dicitonary is structured.

Comment: then put the actual code that generates the dictionary or the actual content of your dictionary.

Comment: will do, one sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always necessary to use pandas for everything.  I've found that it's often much easier to do a little preprocessing before importing to pandas, rather than try to twist my data after it's already in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    "ID: 1": {
        "2022-01-01": [1111, 2222],
        "2022-01-02": [3333, 4444]
    },
    "ID: 2": {
        "2022-01-01": [5555, 6666],
        "2022-01-02": [7777, 8888]
    }
}

build1 = defaultdict(list)
build2 = defaultdict(list)
keys = ['date']+list(data.keys())
for k,v in data.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        build1[k1].append( v1[0] )
        build2[k1].append( v1[1] )
build1 = [[k]+v for k,v in build1.items()]
build2 = [[k]+v for k,v in build2.items()]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(build1, columns=keys).set_index('date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(build2, columns=keys).set_index('date')
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
            ID: 1  ID: 2
date                    
2022-01-01   1111   5555
2022-01-02   3333   7777
            ID: 1  ID: 2
date                    
2022-01-01   2222   6666
2022-01-02   4444   8888
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it is exactly what I need! Personally I would have used only pandas dataframes for the project, but I'm not coding alone and the other person used dictionaries for the data imports and due to limited time we focus on getting it done rather than doing it the 'right' way.

Comment: just tested it and it works flawlessly! Thank you very much! Sadly I'm not able to upvote your answer due to my low reputation, but I will do it once I'm allowed to. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas, it also can be pretty straight forward:

#### Strategy and comments:

*(Value3 added to clarify)* in comments and code

1. Read the nested dict as a dict of dataframes
2. Concat the result in a dataframe

   ```
   df:
              ID1                       ID2             
            Date1        Date2        Date1        Date2
   0  ID1D1Value1  ID1D2Value1  ID2D1Value1  ID2D2Value1
   1  ID1D1Value2  ID1D2Value2  ID2D1Value2  ID2D2Value2
   2  ID1D1Value3  ID1D2Value3  ID2D1Value3  ID2D2Value3
   ```
3. stack: last columns multiindex level goes to last multiindex level

   ```
   df:
                    ID1          ID2
   0 Date1  ID1D1Value1  ID2D1Value1
     Date2  ID1D2Value1  ID2D2Value1
   1 Date1  ID1D1Value2  ID2D1Value2
     Date2  ID1D2Value2  ID2D2Value2
   2 Date1  ID1D1Value3  ID2D1Value3
     Date2  ID1D2Value3  ID2D2Value3
   ```
4. extract the sub dataframes for the first level index values (you need to filter to remove duplicates)

#### Code:

**Data:**

```
data = {
'ID1': {'Date1': ['ID1D1Value1', 'ID1D1Value2', 'ID1D1Value3'], 'Date2': ['ID1D2Value1', 'ID1D2Value2', 'ID1D2Value3']},
'ID2': {'Date1': ['ID2D1Value1', 'ID2D1Value2', 'ID2D1Value3'], 'Date2': ['ID2D2Value1', 'ID2D2Value2', 'ID2D2Value3']}
}
```

**Processing:**

```
df = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in data.items()}, axis=1)
        .stack()
     )

dfs = [df.loc[i] for i in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()]
```

**Result:**

```
>>>
dfs[0]
               ID1          ID2
Date1  ID1D1Value1  ID2D1Value1
Date2  ID1D2Value1  ID2D2Value1


dfs[1]
               ID1          ID2
Date1  ID1D1Value2  ID2D1Value2
Date2  ID1D2Value2  ID2D2Value2


dfs[2]
               ID1          ID2
Date1  ID1D1Value3  ID2D1Value3
Date2  ID1D2Value3  ID2D2Value3
```